# How to search text in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, activerecord

I am trying to implement a search form on my website.

Using the codeigniter active record and mysql I perform the following function in my model:

```
$search_query = 'charge fees for project';

    function get_search_results($search_query){
            $data = '';

            $this->db->like('title', $search_query);
            $this->db->or_like('content', $search_query);               

            $query = $this->db->get('faq'); 

            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'category' => $row->category,
                    'sub_category' => $row->sub_category,
                    'title' => $row->title,
                    'content' => $row->content,
                    'date' => $row->date
                );
            }

            return $data;
    }
```

In my database I have a row that contains the following data:

```
row->title - What fees does the website charge?
row->content - We charges total fees. When your account is successfully project created.
```

My search query returns no results even though these keywords are present in both the title and content. How can I get my search query to pick out the keywords in the database entry and return the result???

Comment: `charge fees for project` doesn't appear as a whole in the title nor content.

Comment: aaah.. ok. so using like, the query needs to appear as a whole. Should the query be split into keywords somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the `search_query` variable before you run the query:

```
$search_query_values = explode(' ', $search_query);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($search_query_values as $key => $value) {
    if ($counter == 0) {
        $this->db->like('title', $value);
    }
    else {
        $this->db->or_like('title', $value);
        $this->db->or_like('content', $value);
    }
    $counter++;
}
$query = $this->db->get('faq');
```

I recommend using the `LIKE` only with `word%` to increase performance. The code:

`$this->db->like('title', $value, 'after');`

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, don't suppose you know how to sort results by relevancy? Guess im on the path to creating my own search engine. lol

Comment: You should use an existing one like sphinx: http://sphinxsearch.com/. Building one yourself will take much more time.

Answer (score 0):

use this instruction carefully

```
$this->db->like('title', $search_query);
```

You are missing to provide after or before in the third parameter. By default it will do it . %my_string%
Read the user guide.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: hmm.. how can I make it pick out those words in the content instead of  trying to match the sentence as a whole?

Comment: $this->db->like('title', $search_query , after); // other is before// please read the user guide or you wouldn't be asking this question